# DB2 Fluent NHibernate mapping duplicate records in HasMany mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping, db2-400

I accessing a pre-existing database (actually DB2 on an IBM i), and have an issue with the mappings for the following (simple) structure in Fluent NHibernate. I have had to construct an artificial example, so forgive any ommissions.

Job ...

```
public class Job
{
    public virtual string JobCode { get; set; }

    public virtual string Owner{ get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Deliverable> Deliverables { get; set; }

    public Job()
    {
        Deliverables = new List<Deliverable>();
    }
}
```

Deliverable ..

```
public class Deliverable
{
    public virtual string JobCode { get; set; }

    public virtual int Package { get; set; }

    public virtual string Owner { get; set; }

    public virtual string Reference { get; set; }

    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to map a 'HasMany' relationship between Job and Deliverable, as follows ..

```
public class JobMap : ClassMap<Job>
{
    public JobMap()
    {
        Table("JOB");

        Id(x => x.JobCode).Column("CODE");

        Map(x => x.Owner).Column("WHODO");

        HasMany(x => x.Deliverables)
            .KeyColumn("CODE");
    }
}

public class DeliverableMap : ClassMap<Deliverable>
{
    public DeliverableMap()
    {
        Table("DELIVERABLE");

        Id(x => x.JobCode).Column("CODE");

        Map(x => x.Reference).Column("UNQREF");

        Map(x => x.Owner).Column("WHODO");

        References( x => x.Job) 
            .Column("CODE") ;
    }
}
```

This seems to work, and if you take the SQL that is produced, and run it directly, the correct results are returned (in this case 11 records, all unique). BUT when I do the following, the list of Deliverables has 11 entries all identical.

IList results = session
    .CreateCriteria(typeof(Job))
    .Add(Expression.Eq("Code", "206171"))
    .List();

```
foreach (var job in results)
{
   Console.WriteLine("job.JobCode" + job.JobCode);
   Console.WriteLine("job.Owner" + job.Owner);

   foreach (var deliverable in job.Deliverables)
   {

     **// These are all identical!**

     Console.WriteLine(deliverable.Reference);
     Console.WriteLine("deliverable.Owner" + deliverable.Owner);
     Console.WriteLine(deliverable.JobNumber);
     Console.WriteLine(deliverable.DeliverableTyoe);
     Console.WriteLine(deliverable.Description);
   }
}
```

So, are the mappings incorrect, or is there something up with the way that I am using them?

Many thanks in advance, I have been staring at this all day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have fixed it. I added CompositeID to the Deliverables mapping

```
 CompositeId()
     .KeyProperty(x => x.JobCode, "CODE")
     .KeyProperty(x => x.Reference, "UNQREF");
```

This meant that I had to override the following in the Deliverable class

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
  if (obj == null)
    return false;

  var t = obj as Deliverable;
  if (t == null)
    return false;

  if (JobCode == t.JobCode && Reference == t.Reference)
    return true;

  return false;
 }

  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
    return (JobCode + "|" + Reference).GetHashCode();
  }
```

and then also changed the Job mapping as below

```
 HasMany(x => x.Deliverables)
   .KeyColumn("Codex")
   .Inverse()
   .Cascade.All();
```

I am not sure which of these has corrected the situation (I suspect the `.Inverse()` in the Job mapping.

I am not sure what the generated SQL now looks like, but the answers look correct.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. As I said, the CODE mapped as ID and also as a referenceId is not sufficient. The missing real unique ID was causing that problem. good you make it working for you. Enjoy NHiberante ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help. It all begins to make sense

Comment: Great ;) really great ;)

Answer (score 1):

In many-to-one relations (in our case `Delivarable` and `Job`), the relation itself is expressed with exactly **one** DB column. The child table (`Deliverable`) has (must have) a reference column with the Job *ID (Code)*.

So, what we need for our mapping, is the column inside the Delivarable table, containing the relation to the Job. The `JobCode` column. (Not sure if there is any, from example above)

And this must be used on both sides:

Delivarable:

```
public DeliverableMap()
{
    ...
    // References( x => x.Deliverable) ... I guess it is typo in the question snippet
    References( x => x.Job) 
        .Column("JobCode") ; // column of table Deliverable
}
```

Job:

```
public JobMap()
{
    ...
    HasMany(x => x.Deliverables)
        .KeyColumn("JobCode");  // column of table Deliverable
}
```

Other words, both column names in this mapping, are in fact the names of **one** column. Both are mapped to child (Deliverable) table's column.

EXTENDED: based on mapping changes in the question

The `Deliverable` object, has its `ID` (column CODE) the same as the reference to `Job` (column CODE). This seems to be weird.

That's also explaining the fact, that all the Deliverable items inside the JOB collection are the **same** (identical). Unique Deliverable (defined by its CODE) can be only one. The Job in this scenario cannot have more then one Deliverable (because it's referenced by unique CODE column). It seems like **the one-to-one** scenario.

The reason why there are **more** items **same** is harder to judge. It would be good to see the query you are using.

But I would really twice check the column mapping. Deliverable, should have reference to Job in a column called "JobCODE"... supporting more Delivrables to be related...

Comment: Thanks - I have corrected the errors in my original question. My code is basically as you suggest above. The SQL generated, when copied and run locally produces the required results, however the collection of Deliverables produced by my code has the correct number of results, but with indentical results.

Comment: I extend my answer. What seems really weired to me is the "code" column as ID and Job reference...

Comment: The actual files have the same field name for the field that is used to join them - the Deliverable has a 'composite' key made up of this and a unique reference - i.e.     Job (1) -> Deliverable (1) (1),  Job (1) -> Deliverable (1) (2),  Job (1) -> Deliverable (1) (3),  Job (1) -> Deliverable (2) (1), etc. (sorry about the formatting)

Comment: Sorry, if I do not get it. But your mapping says: ID to CODE and ReferenceId to CODE. This seems to be a problem to me. But maybe I do not udnerstand correctly. If you mapp (as in your snippet) using the CODE and the CODE is the ID (unique) then to me it seems to be the problem. **Suggestion**: Provide the real mapping. Only then we can find the issue ;)

Comment: Each of the underlying tables has a field called "CODE", not much I can do about this. This appears to be the cause of the issue. Even if I change the names of the fields in the classes, the underlying field names seem to interfere. As I originally posted, the SQL that gets produced does actually 'work', it seems to just be Fluent NHibernate that gets confused.